# Media Playback of Recorded Audio not able to play on speaker on Android

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, audio-recording

I am making a Call recorder app in Android. I have a service that detects the incoming and outgoing call and as soon as the service detects the incoming or outgoing call it starts the recording through media player. It is getting recorded sucessfully but I am unable to play it on speaker. The volume is very low  even after enabling speakers through Audio Manager. Please let me know where I might be going wrong.

Note: I am guessing that my audio is not getting recorded properly because if I play the recorded file through my phone music player, then even there I am not able to play that file on speaker.

below is my code which is used to start the recording:

```
try{
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    if(AUDIO_SOURCE_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("VOICE_COMMUNICATION"))
         {
             mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
         }
         else if(AUDIO_SOURCE_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("VOICE_UPLINK"))
         {
             mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK);
         }
         else if(AUDIO_SOURCE_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("VOICE_DOWNLINK"))
         {
             mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
         }
         else if(AUDIO_SOURCE_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("MIC"))
         {
             mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
         }
         else if(AUDIO_SOURCE_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("DEFAULT"))
         {
             mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
         }
         else
         {
             mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
         }
         mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
         mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getTempFilename());
         mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
         mediaRecorder.prepare();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

        mediaRecorder.start();
```

Below is the Media Playback Code :

```
final MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer(); 
String uri= getIntent().getStringExtra("fileURI"); //fetches the string defining the path of file to be played
Uri fileURI = Uri.parse(uri);
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
AudioManager mAudioManager  = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

        try{  
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), fileURI);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
           }
        mp.prepare();  
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  
mp.start();
```

Comment: Experiment with other Audio codes namely `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC`.

Comment: Hi Neo I have already tried all combinations but it is not giving me the desired result. The recorded audio is playing when I hear closely to my phone but it is not getting played on speaker. Do you suggest any changes in the Playback settings ?

Comment: The source itself that you are using may not be good enough. How about the sound quality when you download and play them on a PC? That way you atleast know its not a Playback problem. Also did you try this on multiple devices? It could be a device issue.

Comment: I tried running it on PC it throws an error that the codec I am using to compress the file may be incorrect. It was originally tested on HTC one. Now I also tried on Nexus 5 but the quality is even more poor on nexus 5. Any other hint ?

Comment: Also I would like to point out that this media player is running inside a service. I hope that is not creating a problem. Because I has a sample program referred from here http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Audio_Recording_and_Playback_using_MediaPlayer_and_MediaRecorder which is running perfectly fine and the way i desire

Comment: Hi Neo, I am able to play the file through VLC player on PC but not WMP. I still cannot figure out the issue !!